# Summing up of corresponding elements of two arrays or more

Tags: arrays, sum

Enter a number: 10

Even Numbers:   0 2 4 6 8 10
Odd Numbers:    1 3 5 7 9
Prime Numbers:  2 3 5 7
Sum :          3 8 14 20 17 10
i wanted to sum up the corresponding elements of the array like above what should i do???

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question to clearly explain what you have and what you need / where it is going wrong. If you have 3 arrays for example, then keep an `i = 0`, and increment this to `max(max(len(arr1), len(arr2)), len(arr3))` - meaning the max count of the 3 arrays.

A `for` loop can go from `i=0` to `i=max-value-above` and then you can generate a new array by summing up the values of each array at that index `i`, taking care that you don't go out of bounds for each array.